# My typeorm (nestjs) raw sql query is hanging and not producing any output, no errors either

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

i have this code in a consumer

```js
const runner = this.connection.createQueryRunner();
const selectQuery = await runner.query(
  'select * from nonExistentTable;',
  [entity.id],
);
console.log('select: ', selectQuery)
```

When I execute this it just hangs and there is no error or result, nothing happens and the function just hangs, I made sure the connection is connected and it is, the database connection works and when I log the connection it does give me an error (regular sql error relation not found) but I don't understand why the function doesn't error out, I am expecting this to be the default behavior